firebase_storage/channel-error Unable to establish connection on channel
I'm trying to connect Firebase Storage to my flutter project. But I got an error

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
Exception: [firebase_storage/channel-error] Unable to establish
connection on channel.

I've found that it could be problem with rules because I've used firebase auth. But my rules in the storage looks like this:
rules_version = '2';
    service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write : if request.auth !=null;
    }
  }
}

I've also tried :
allow read, write : if true

but it has the same problem
I've changed my build.gradle by adding dependencies
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:21.0.0")

My Code:
Reference get firebaseStorage => FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

    class FirebaseStorageService extends GetxService{
    
    static Future<String?> getImage(String? imgName) async{

    if(imgName == null){
      return null;
    }
    try{
     var urlRef = firebaseStorage
          .child("images")
          .child('$imgName.png');

     var imgUrl = await urlRef.getDownloadURL(); //here is a problem

     return imgUrl;
    }catch (e){
      throw e;
      return null;
    }
  }
}


See also: Flutter - Firebase, Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Is it Flutter for WEB?
If so, this is most likely a CORS problem:

add file cors.json

insert content below

run: gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<bucket_name>
[
{
"origin": [
"*"
],
"method": [
"GET",
"POST",
"PUT",
"DELETE",
"OPTIONS"
],
"maxAgeSeconds": 3600,
"responseHeader": [
"Content-Type",
"Authorization"
]
}
]



Hi @Dewey, I'm facing this issue for my web app, written in Flutter, I'm using FIrebase Hosting to host the app. Tried this same for my CORS config, still facing the same issue.

Had the same issue. This helped:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build web


if you are deploying it using firebase hosting and are using service worker like me, you have to make sure your index.html imported the script for firebase storage as well, in my case i have a service worker like so:
Also make sure you set up your CORS correctly
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-storage-compat.js'); //import this

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "--",
    authDomain: "--",
    projectId: "--",
    storageBucket: "--",
    messagingSenderId: "--",
    appId: "--"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
const storage = firebase.storage(); //declare this

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log('Received background message ', payload);

    const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.data.body,
      };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});

now all you have to do is register your service worker in your index.html on your html body like this (in my case my service worker name is firebase-messaging-sw.js):
    <script>
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js", { scope: '/' })
          .then((registration) => {
            console.log('Service Worker registered with scope:', registration.scope);
          }).catch((err) => {
            console.error('Service Worker registration failed:', err);
          });
      });
    }
  </script>

It should work now

Normally Ai give us this kind of answer
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

But i have to put some more information for the connection here is my code
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if(Platform.isAndroid) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: FirebaseOptions(
            apiKey: 'AIzaSyB9m84p8Y_SY6isFvMaOFWOA2g4xKrb6Nc',
            appId: '1:773723122783:android:b26d30ed175962b3413fea',
            messagingSenderId: '773723122783',
            projectId: 'untitled-38d04')
    );
  }
  Get.put(auth());
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

check both of them and put it in main screeen hope it will help
